# Spring GET endpoint returns unexpected HTML error response

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I am returning a response from a GET endpoint like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
......
......
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getFeatureById(@PathVariable(name = "id", required = true) UUID id) {
    MyObject myObj = myService.getObjectById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<MyObject>(myObj, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

MyObject is a simple class:

```
public class MyObject {

    private UUID id;

    public MyObject(UUID id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But this returns error response:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style 
 type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background- 
 color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a 
 {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP 
 Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1></body></html>
```

MyObject instance is correctly created, still error is returned and that too in HTML form. What am I doing wrong here?

Application log shows no error as 500:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-06T17:05:11.939+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/feature-eval-storage-service]","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"application.version":"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT","application.name":"feature-eval-storage-service"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-06T17:05:11.939+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"application.version":"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT","application.name":"feature-eval-storage-service"}
{"@timestamp":"2020-06-06T17:05:11.945+05:30","@version":"1","message":"Completed initialization in 5 ms","logger_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"application.version":"0.0.1-SNAPSHOT","application.name":"feature-eval-storage-service"}
```

Comment: Status 500 - Internal Server Errors tells that something is wrong with request processing on the server side. Check the application logs, you should see an error there

Comment: Please share the whole stacktrace from the log, if you get a 500 then there must be an exception in the log. Maybe the exception is being thrown in the myService.getObjectById, share this code too.